# Make Jenkins Build fail if docker container container exited

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, docker-compose, continuous-deployment

I have a job that Deploys the app into a Docker container, the build success, The Docker container is up. let's say that after 10 min the docker container Exited (Down), how can I handle this? 
I don't think that keeping the job running is a good idea. I want something like a trigger from Docker to Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the job running is not a good idea. If after 10 mins, an exited container is most likely due to a crash in your application.

What you can do is when running the container you can specify a [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart) for when the container exists. That way your container will be automatically restarted.

Another solution would be is to create a schedueled jenkins job that checks if your container is alive, and if not sends you an email ...

Comment: Yeah, Creating another job sounds good, regarding the restart policy I'm using Docker-compose still don't know how to implement the restart process. cuz container depends on another one